# Really installing PyQt4/5 for python 3.4 on trusty

Tags: python, qt, python3, matplotlib

I am using Python 3 on my ubuntu 14.04.2 (trusty), along with Python 2. I am trying to run `ipython --pylab`, but with Python 3, this fails (works well with Python 2). It fails since it needs QT4/5 or PySide.

I [could not install PySide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007733/pip-install-pyside-fails), but I could easily install PyQt4 with

```
sudo aptitude install python3-pyqt4 python3-pyqt5
```

However, that doesn't seem to do the job. The output of `ipython --pylab` is

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtCore'
```

`matplotlib` throws that error after trying to import `QtCore` from `PyQt5`. Funny thing, it fails exactly there even if PyQt5 is purged (but with the error `No module named`PyQt5`)

Is there anything wrong with either `matplotlib` or with the `python3-pyqt4/5` packages? Is it possible that `python-pyqt4/5` do not even support `python3.4`?

## Update

After purging `python3-pyqt4` and `python3-pyqt5` and installing `python3-pyside` instead, `ipython` worked well with `pylab`. This is documented in the SO question I was linking to.

Now, with `pyside` installed, I have installed `python3-pyqt5` again in order to answer a question from the comments, and now `QtCore` is properly imported (both in `python` and in `ipython`), but `pylab` is not working again.

The error is, however, much different:

```
ImportError: 
    Could not load requested Qt binding. Please ensure that
    PyQt4 >= 4.7, PyQt5 or PySide >= 1.0.3 is available,
    and only one is imported per session.

    Currently-imported Qt library:   'pyqt5'
    PyQt4 installed:                 False
    PyQt5 installed:                 False
    PySide >= 1.0.3 installed:       True
    Tried to load:                   ['pyqt5']
```

Now, typing `%pylab` again from within the `ipython` console **works**. This is a very weird behaviour.

## Update (2)

It seems that `pyside`, without the ubuntu package `python3-pyqt5`, does not really work. I can run `ipython --pylab` with no errors that way, but when I try to `plot()` or to `scatter()`, it fails with

```
AttributeError: 'figure()' is not a Qt property or a signal
```

So, it seems the only way I can make `pylab` work **properly**, it to install both `python3-pyside` and `python3-pyqt5`, see the weird `ImportError` quoted above, trying `%pylab` **again**, and work.

Comment: Can you run `from PyQt5 import QtCore`  in the standard Python shell (`python` and `python3`) instead of IPython?

Comment: I'm confused - are you invoking ipython as `ipython` or `ipython3`?

Comment: @EricCarvalho, updated my question. steeldriver, on my machine `ipython` **is** `ipython3`.

Comment: Installing python packages from the Ubuntu repository usually gives you antique software. Install the latest stable version from PyPI using the `pip`/`pip3` command: `sudo pip3 install PyQt5` or whichever package you want. It's also a good idea to upgrade `pip` itself first: `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip`. Maybe you should run this upgrade command for all packages you need and have problems with.

Comment: @ByteCommander, there is no pip package `PyQt5`. There is a package `python-qt5`, but it seems to be for [Windows only](https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5).

Comment: You seem right... Don't know then. :-(

Comment: What is the value of `backend.qt` in your rcparams?

Comment: `rcParams['backend']` is `Qt5Agg`, but the key `backend.qt` does not exist.