# Python3 + ipython + pylab on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python3, qt5, ipython, pyside, pyqt5

I really want to switch to Python 3, but Ubuntu 14.04 makes it difficult to do so when using the IPython+pylab framework.

My settings: I have installed most of the important packages using `pip` rather than `aptitude`. Thes packages include **numpy 1.10.1**, **scipy 0.16.1**, **matplotlib 1.5.0**, **pylab 0.1.0** and **IPython 4.0.1**.

I have also installed **python3-pyqt5 5.2.1** and **python3-pyside 1.2.1** using `aptitude`.

Using `matplotlib` from within `IPython` works well:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0, 1], [1, 2])
plt.show()
```

But the problem starts when I try to use `pylab`, either by calling `ipython --pylab` or by calling `pylab` from within IPython. This is what I get in both of these cases:

```
ImportError: 
    Could not load requested Qt binding. Please ensure that
    PyQt4 >= 4.7, PyQt5 or PySide >= 1.0.3 is available,
    and only one is imported per session.

    Currently-imported Qt library:   'pyqt5'
    PyQt4 installed:                 False
    PyQt5 installed:                 False
    PySide >= 1.0.3 installed:       True
    Tried to load:                   ['pyqt5']
```

So, if I understand it properly, it does not recognize that `PyQt5` is installed. This is weird for two reasons; first, `import PyQt5` and `import PyQt5.QtCore` both don't complain. The second reason is that a second call to pylab works perfectly, and with Qt5!

```
Using matplotlib backend: Qt5Agg
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
```

However, there's another consequence for this. After plotting, successfully (say, with `plot([0, 1], [1, 2])`), when I exit IPython using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

This is a problem I have for about 3 months now. I have already posted a couple of questions here: [Really installing PyQt4/5 for python 3.4 on trusty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661346/really-installing-pyqt4-5-for-python-3-4-on-trusty) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007733/pip-install-pyside-fails. I have tried probably almost all combinations of installing pyside/pyqt5/numpy/scipy/matplotlib/ipython/pylab via pip/aptitude. Nothing seems to work properly.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 14.04, I could start `ipython` and then import PyQt5, but if I run `ipython --matplotlib qt5`, it states `pyqt5` is not installed.

I then looked into the code and saw in the file `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/IPython/external/qt_loaders.py`, that `ipython` checks for `QtCore`, `QtGui`, `Qtsvg` and in the case of `pyqt5` also for `qtwidgets`.
Naturally, I did have `QtCore`, `QtGui` and `QtWidgets` installed, but not `Qtsvg`. I ran synaptic and installed `Qtsvg` for `pyqt5` (that is `python3-pyqt5.qtsvg`). Now it works.

**TL;DR:** Install the `python3-pyqt5.qtsvg` package:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtsvg
```

Comment: Loving you for that pointer, thanks! The error message should really be more specific.